# pgAdmin 4 how to see current restore jobs?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

On pgAdmin 4 v3.1, I right click a database, click Restore, choose a backup file and click go.

A little green popup says "Restore job created" which fades away, but no other indicator shows a restore under way. There used to be a window that stayed open indicating that a restore is under way and total time that has passed.

How to see current restore jobs / know when it has been completed?

I've tried restarting PC, reinstalling pgadmin, clicking File > reset layout, creating new db.

The docs suggest the window indicating a restore is happening should be visible. So I guess I'm facing a bug? https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/restore_dialog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pgAdmin 4 v3.3, the restore popup window is back, so you can again easily see when restore is finished.

Comment: ...and then gone again (pgAdmin4 v4.22). It looks like they are gone after opening two windows in the same session, but I haven't got the opportunity to triage it adequately

Comment: Any help with v6.3? I'm restoring and can't get any feedback to what's going on

Comment: @Noam I haven't used it, but maybe try the other answer to see a list of processes.

Comment: @Andrew - the other answer, just shows the session info and current running query - I want to see the text output of pgdump/pgrestore. There used to be a dialog (that is described on the docs) that shows that info - and I can't get that window in the latest version

Answer (score 2):

Well pgAdmin 4 is definitely bug riddled, but found an answer to this.

To see current restore jobs:

1. Set to true: File > Preferences > Dashboard > Display > Show Activity
2. Refresh if needed, then open Dashboard > Sessions
3. Start your restore job, then hit refresh on the sessions.

You'll see a new process listed, and can click the (play icon ?) for more details about it.

The process disappears after restore is completed.

Comment: how long it takes to restore database? as it takes too long

Comment: I don't know I haven't used it in a while! Did it finish yet? Probably depends on size of the db and your pc. 2 minutes - 2 hours ?